# Incorrect API key in Firebase account activation and password reset emails

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

I have a Web application in my Firebase project. Under the project settings I can see my Firebase API key. I use that key my Firebase config and everything works as expected. My app users can sign up, login and create data in Firestore using my web app. I know what the correct Firebase API key is.

The problem is that the Firebase account activation or password reset emails contain incorrect API key. They key that the links contain is a different API key that I created in the GCP project that I use for Google Maps API.

```
https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=EeKw-udvLGXYCEclQ-hFbDUq7TIqpjZhPVkjh6ek1ykkjlkjl&apiKey=THIS_IS_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY_AND_NOT_MY_FIREBASE_KEY&lang=en
```

The query string is automatically generated by Firebase. I'm at a total loss of how to troubleshoot this.

Why would Firebase send incorrect key?
How to fix this ?